# How does the Egg-Medusa move?

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures, animal-locomotion

The egg-medusa is a small terrestrial being with a strange appearance: It resembles a human head without any neck, and instead of hair it has many avian heads and necks growing out of it, which cover continuously the scalp, back of the head, neck-space, and chin

The human head part is 12cm from the chin to the parietals, with the avian heads extending 6cm from their root in the skull

The bird-heads are capable of motion and are quite flexible. They can also be coordinated centrally by the human part

**Given their external anatomy, what is the most realistic way they could get around on land?**

Comment: What is a parietals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Walking Upright.**

[image]

Some of the bird heads work like legs. Since the creature needs to see where it's going, it is the bottom necks that will be the legs. Depending on how strong and rigid they are, you get something like the above -- where the body is raised above the ground --  or how an octopus drags itself around.

[image]

Comment: there's an awesome video of the octopus walking on land - you should really link to it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebeNeQFUMa0

Answer (score 1):

## Keep Your Chin Up!

I think such an organism would use the bird heads/necks to walk as Daron suggests (obviously), BUT I suspect it would move about chin-up with the "top" of the head towards the ground. So the head would appear to be upside down as it moved. Then all the little heads would work collectively like for an awkward centipede.

Answer (score 1):

It teleports.

That is the reason it has so many heads: the multiple brains give it the mental power to harness this kind of magic.